# Is it a security hole to get Safari Apple ID Two-Factor Authentication codes on the same Mac?

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication

If I am not misinformed, the idea of two-factor authentication is that if an attacker somehow gets my Apple ID and password, they have an additional hurdle to overcome.

But it seems to me that this is NOT an obstacle given the behavior shown here:

[image]

All I have to do (when it's really me) is drag the pop-up out of the way and copy the number directly.  A minor inconvenience, but (so it seems) doesn't keep the intruder out.

Of course, they have to also have one of my devices, but one iPhone disappeared in restaurant in Indiana, another in a subway in Barcelona, and an iPad in Oklahoma (and the same iPad was out of my reach on a train for a night¹).

However, maybe I'm missing something, because Apple seems unconcerned—I reported this as a bug more than sixteen months ago, and there has been no response.

So, am I missing something?

¹When traveling by train in Spain, never take more objects than you can carry.  The train will leave while you are setting down the first load on the platform.

Comment: Also interesting is the words "new device."  I use multiple Apple services on this device with the same ID _every_day_.

Comment: Two factor is "something you know, and something you have".  You know the password, you have the Mac.  This is not a security issue, it's no different than you having your TOTP app running on that same Mac while you try to log in.  If you think the codes should be sent somewhere else, configure the somewhere else as a trusted device.

Comment: They're all trusted.  The code does appear on the others, but it still appears on the one being used.  So if they have my password and they have my mac, it's a security problem, unless, as in my question, I'm missing something.

Comment: @MarcWilson i have never figured out how to change my trusted devices - i have a mac VM that i do not want to be a trusted device. However, because the vm is logged in to icloud, it automatically became a trusted device. The only way to make it untrusted would be to log it out of icloud, which i would rather not do. This is the same case with a 2011 imac i keep around for display. Is there a way to make devices logged in to icloud yet not trusted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WGroleau if someone stole your device, you could use find my to temporarily lock it, preventing any codes/logins from getting there

Comment: @anonymous: If I were fast enough to do it before it connected to internet.  Your other comment should be posted as a new question.

Comment: TOTP code will only be visible when your device is **unlocked**. Unless they know your device passcode/password, otherwise they wouldn't be able to get it.

Comment: For what it's worth, Apple either agreed that it's a security flaw or they had some other reason for changing the behavior, because it hasn't happened for some time.  Now (including pre-Ventura) the code is NOT displayed on the device asking for it.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not a "hole" in security - this is definitely by design.

The idea behind 2-factor authentication is that a user is required to present 2 separate and different factors of authentication. These factors can be many things, but in Apple's system they are a password (something you know) and a token (something you have) stored on your computer.

This improves security when compared with just authenticating using a single factor, username and password, as was common not so many years ago:

If someone compromises your password and tries to login to your iCloud account from their own computer, they will not be able to login as they cannot produce the 6 digit verification code.

Similarly if someone compromises your authentication token (for example by extracting it from a stolen backup drive) and tries to login to your iCloud account from their own computer, they will not be able to login as they cannot enter the correct account password.

Finally, if someone has physical possession of both one of your trusted devices as well as knowing your iCloud password, they still have one barrier left to pass. For example stealing your iPhone or iPad won't automatically give the thief access to your verification codes - they aren't displayed unless the device is unlocked (using for example TouchID/FaceID or a passcode).

Should someone know your iCloud password, have your device in their possession - and be able to unlock it - then you're out of luck. This is to be expected and is by design.

It is always a good idea to follow simple practices such as:

- Do not reuse passwords amongst multiple services
- Do not use the same password for your iCloud account as for your Mac user account or iOS device passcode
- Use a strong passphrase for your Mac user account - especially if you have your iCloud account password stored in a Keychain in your Mac
- Enable Find My on compatible devices and ensure that you mark them as missing/stolen as soon as you know that has happened
- Always keep devices updated with security-related software upgrades

In addition to these practices, it is worth knowing that modern devices usually have the best security. I.e. an 2021 Apple Silicon MacBook Pro will have better security than a 2012 Intel MacBook Pro. Similarly an iPhone 13 Pro will have better security than an iPhone 5S.

Comment: All correct and all known by me before I asked—except for one paragraph.  You implied that Apple DESIGNED what looks like a point of failure which is the particular irritation I asked about.

Comment: As far as I know, the only reason a 2012 MBP has poorer security is that it can't run the latest software.

Comment: Well, it isn’t really possible for others to know what you know before we write our answers - and they’re not really written only for you. But if you know everything in advance, why ask? And no, it’s not a point of failure - but I guess you already know that.

Comment: In that case you’re misinformed. It’s not just that it cannot run the latest software. The same applies for later models as well.

Comment: I knew what you wrote.  I did not know what I asked.  What is there about _hardware_ that makes one more secure than another?  (Which is really a separate question.)

Comment: I take it that you do not like my answer - not really sure why though. Regarding hardware - the evolution from a "bare" Intel machine like the 2012 MacBook Pro over T1 Macs over T2 Macs to the Apple-silicon Macs involves a LOT of security related hardware improvements. Your token for the verification codes is much better secured on an Apple Silicon-Mac than on a T1 Mac for example.

Comment: @WGroleau What is this point of failure you think they've designed into it?

Comment: @MarcWilson: _Apple_ says that showing the code on the same device that asks for the code is by design!

Comment: You're the one using the same device for both - not Apple.

Comment: @WGroleau I'm not sure why people think that's a security problem.  These are typically the same people that don't have a problem with their favorite TOTP app running on the same computer on which they're browing the website asking them for the TOTP code.

Comment: I am NOT one of those people.  I don't even know what TOTP means.  I do not like being told that I have to enter a code shown on another device when it is actually shown on the SAME device.  That is obviously does NOT add any security!

Comment: I think you need to read the message again. It does not say that it is shown on "another device" - that is just something you have somehow misunderstood. For anyone that do understand what TOTP means, this obviously adds to the security.

Comment: Apple sends the code to ALL our devices, including the one that is allegedly protected by requiring the code.  Whoever they are supposedly protecting it from can read the code ON THAT DEVICE.  Thus my belief that it is NOT protection.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood how this works. Apple is not sending the code anywhere. That's not how it works. The code is not sent to all of your devices - it's not sent to any of your devices.